# Indexing a cell in MATLAB with a vector

Tags: matlab

Assume that I am given the cell `M`, and a vector `v`, and assume that `v` holds a correct address for an element in `M`. Without any apriori knowledge of the structure of `M` and `v`, I wish to fetch the element from `M` that `v` points to. How can I do this? For instance, `M{v}` does not quite do what I need:

say `M = cell(3,4,5)`, `v = [1,2,3]`, then doing `M{v}` produces `[M{1}, M{2}, M{3}]`.

So my question is: how can I encapsulate an address of a cell element into a variable `v` and later fetch the element at that address from the given cell?

The same question for any array instead of cell.

Comment: Can't understand your problem. What's wrong with fetching elements by indexes? If it's what you're actually trying to do, then you should simply change curly brackets to round ones, e.g. `M(v)`. Or maybe you're trying to get a pointer to some element to mutate it later (like we do in C)?

Comment: In your example, what would you want to obtain instead of `[M{1}, M{2}, M{3}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v` has to be a cell not a vector, then you can use `sub2ind`:

```
v=mat2cell(v(:),ones(numel(v),1))
M(sub2ind(size(M),v{:}))
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like in place of the second line, I can just do `M{v{:}}`, which is what I really need.